# Quasar q-icon to use icon in assets folder

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have an icon named "home.svg" in my *assets folder*. how can I direct my `q-icon` component to get the icon inside the `assets/` directory.

I have tried applying this way:

```
  <q-icon name="img:/assets/home.svg" class="text-dark" style="font-size: 32px;" />
```

but the image is not being rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `default` slot. And see [Asset Resolving Rules](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/handling-assets#Asset-Resolving-Rules).

```html
<q-icon class="text-dark" size="lg">
  <img src="~assets/home.svg" />
</q-icon>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of Quasar you were using while writing this post, but Quasar (V2 as for today) has support for image / SVG files.
So your way should work now:

```html
<q-icon name='img:path/to/img' />
```

You can see the related docs [here](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon#qicon-api)

[image].

Comment: No this does not work using ~assets the accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because for me, it worked.
@scott Which Quasar version are you using?
Make sure you're aligned with their docs.
If still it doesn't work, you should open an issue in Quasar repo

Comment: the documents literally say to use ~assets

Comment: I checked it now. It's still the same docs as I pasted here.
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon/#qicon-api. 
Go to `QIconAPI -> Props -> Model`, there you'll see the `name` prop. press `+` for expanded description, and read what they write there (don't forget to check their examples).

Comment: as mentioned the accepted answer is the correct one you must use ~assets as per the docs. https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-assets#Asset-Resolving-Rules